# Using a Clover <fileset> on Hudson

Tags: java, ant, hudson, fileset, clover

We're trying to limit Clover to a certain package and therefore have a [`<fileset>`](http://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CLOVER/clover-setup#clover-setup-Fileset) definition in our Ant build file. Everything works fine from the command line (when we specify our known Ant target). But when it comes to the Clover plug-in on Hudson, we don't know which Ant target Hudson uses. Any pointers in using a Clover `<fileset>` on Hudson?

Comment: Are you using the Scriptless integration?  http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Clover+Plugin

Comment: @Zac Thompson: Yes, the idea was to get it working with scriptless integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would it be possible to invoke the ant target explicitly as a build step directly (via an Ant step), and then point Hudson at your Clover results via the post-build option? This is how we currently use Hudson+Clover.

Comment: Just to confirm, with this approach, you can view the Clover results within the job result view, right?

Comment: We've peeked into the clover.xml that comes with the Clover plugin jar and copied the clover.report target into our own Ant build file. We have a clover.setup target that defines the `<fileset>`. In Hudson we run clover.setup, then our own build target and then finally the clover.report target. We then let Hudson collect the Clover results.